# Debug multiple javascript files in VSCode

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a javascript project containing multiple files that reference each other.
In a browser context, all of those files would be loaded via a script tag.
I want to debug my project in VSCode, because I only need the terminal and it is more convenient.
How can I get VSCode to also have the other files in it's scope while debugging? Like you would debug Python for example (which ofc always has all programs running in scope). Is there something like import? Or has it to do with the launch.json file?
Thank you for your help.